# How to resize images in a node-red flow

Tags: node.js, image, node-red

I have a node red flow where i get some images from a REST API as binary buffers in png or jpg format.

Motivation: Some people do not pay attention and post very large pics to a blog service. Since the service is limited in its amount of storage for pics I want to listen to the stream of events and resize every incoming picture to "longest side = 1024" while keeping the aspect ratio like it is.

Now I have the binary objects as buffer in my flow - but how to resize an image in a node-red flow? I did search for half a day but did not find a node which is capable of doing that. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up making jimp available publicly by adding the entry "jimp":"0.2.x", to the package.json dependencies and adding into functionGlobalContext in the settings.js:

```
functionGlobalContext: {
       mcrypto:require('crypto'),
       Jimp:require('jimp')
},
```

Now I can easily use it in a function node by simply writing:

```
var JIMP = global.get("Jimp");
msg.image2 = {};
JIMP.read(msg.payload).then(function(image) {
    msg.image.width = image.bitmap.width;
    msg.image.height = image.bitmap.height;

    if (image.bitmap.height > image.bitmap.width){
        if (image.bitmap.height > 800){
            image.resize(JIMP.AUTO, 800)
            msg.image2.width = image.bitmap.width;
            msg.image2.height = image.bitmap.height;
            image.getBuffer(image.getMIME(), onBuffer);
        }
    }
    else {
            if (image.bitmap.width > 800){
            image.resize(800, JIMP.AUTO)
            msg.image2.width = image.bitmap.width;
            msg.image2.height = image.bitmap.height;
            image.getBuffer(image.getMIME(), onBuffer);
        }
    }
}).catch(function (err) {
    // handle an exception
    if (err) throw err;
});

function onBuffer (err, buffer) {
    if (err) throw err;
    msg.payload = buffer;
    node.send(msg);
}

return ;
```

This way I solved my need. Better ideas welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a Node-RED node that will do that for you at the moment. You'll probably have to write your own Node-RED node, there are instructions on how to get started on the Node-RED doc site [here](https://nodered.org/docs/creating-nodes/).

There are a bunch of [ImageMagick](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=imagemagick&page=1&ranking=optimal) nodes on npm which would probably be a good starting point or also the [sharp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sharp) module looks like another good candidate.

Comment: I have found this and will give it a try. Report here later. https://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-contrib-viseo-jimp